# URL issues, after a link is clicked on via email -- What's the deal? ##

Tags: url, friendly-url, fragment-identifier

My app is sending users email with the following:

https://blah.chacha.com/feedback/##comment-reply-169

But for some reason, sometimes when the URL is loaded in some of the user's browsers the ## are being converted to something like:

https://blah.chacha.com/feedback/#%23comment-reply-169

Any ideas what's going on here and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#` character isn’t valid in a [fragment identifier](http://labs.apache.org/webarch/uri/rfc/rfc3986.html#fragment), so it’s being escaped automatically. You should either avoid using that character inside a fragment, or explicitly `unescape` the value before using it.